# Who is the assassin at the end of The Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

OK, I figured out that the Grandmaster was actually Alvin. That wasn't hard.

But who was the assassin in the end animation? I mean both the king and Gerald shared a weird look after Gerald unmasked him. So was that just because the problems didn't end, or was it someone from the story-line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither Geralt nor the king recognize the assassin, as revealed in The Witcher 2. His noteworthy trait, and the reason why they both share a weird look after the unmasking, is the fact that the assassin is also a Witcher, as indicated by his eyes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that :-/

Comment: I'd argue for including more information on the Assassin in a second paragraph protected by spoiler tags.